# Integral Of $\oint_{0}^{1+i} f(z)dz$ , $f(z)=y-x-3x^2 i$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to evaluate the following:
$$\int_{0}^{1+i} f(z)\ dz$$
$f(z)=y-x-3x^2 i$

I need to present $z$ with some $t$, I dont know how to make the connection between them.

Hints? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of contour are you integrating over?  Are $0$ and $1+i$ the starting/ending points of the curve?  I ask this because the way the problem is currently written doesn't make sense.

Comment: start from $0$ to $1+i$

Comment: So what kind of curve is it? A line?

Comment: Yes, its a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're integrating over the line $z(t)= t+ti$ for $t\in[0,1]$, take $x=t$ and $y=t$ and substitute this into $f(z)=y-x-3x^2i$.  Then, once you make the appropriate substitutions, it follows that
$$\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz \xrightarrow{z=t+ti}{} \int_0^1 -3t^2i(1+i)\,dt = \ldots$$

Comment: Why we need to take $x=t$ and $y=t$?

Comment: Since $f(z)=f(x+iy)=y-x-3x^2i$ and you're integrating over the line segment $z(t)=t+ti$ for $t\in[0,1]$, it should be clear that you need to take $x=t$ and $y=t$; the computation of this integral should be treated like any line integral -- you want to substitute the parameterization into $f(z)$ in order to get an integral we can actually compute.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a straight line from $0$ to $1+i$,

**HINT:** First, represent $f(z)$ in terms of $z$,

$$x=\frac{z+\overline {z}}{2},\ y=\frac{z-\overline {z}}{2i}$$
 then let $z=x+xi,\ x \in [0,1]$ be the parameterization of the line.

Comment: I solved some test, and it was the question

Comment: what about $y$ and $x$ they equal?

Comment: I have edited my answer to tailor to your question.